# Почему и где нужны запятые? И нужны ли?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и

> Океан словно замер и тихо и ласково рокочет...

Answer (score 2):

Мне не нравится, когда ради учебных целей кромсают предложение. Да еще и оформляют его с ошибками. При "обрыве" в конце необходимо ставить многоточие.
Вот оно — оригинальное (кстати, это, как мне кажется, неплохой пример для разрешения вопроса об однородных сказуемых разного вида):

> Океан словно замер **и** тихо **и** ласково рокочет, переливаясь утихавшей зыбью.

Союзы **и** поставлены на разном основании, поэтому запятые не требуются:
первый — между однородными сказуемыми (*океан замер **и** рокочет*);
второй — между однородными обстоятельствами, относящимися ко второму сказуемому (*рокочет тихо **и** ласково*).

Здесь же имеется, думаю, *наинтереснейшее* предложение с комплексом из четырех союзов **и** (а запятая нигде не нужна!):

> Он тих **и** необыкновенно нежен **и** только глухо шумит **и** пенится у берега, разбиваясь о скалы **и** катаясь бурунами по каменным грядкам.

[Знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения с союзами и без союзов](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112) (ПАС)
[К. М. Станюкович. Вокруг света на «Коршуне»](https://litlife.club/books/25736/read?page=34)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед первым союзом "И" не нужна, так он соединяет однородные сказуемые
"замер" и "рокочет".

Запятая перед вторым союзом "И" не нужна, так он соединяет однородные обстоятельства "тихо" и "ласково".

То есть это не повторящийся союзом "И... И".

Comment: То есть можно "тихо и ласково" опустить и рассмотреть союз "и" между однородными сказуемыми, а затем так же поступить с однородными обстоятельствами?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что "словно" относится только к "замер", поэтому первый союз "и" не нужно убирать. А второй союз "и" можно убрать.